# What to use as hover effect for an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to achieve the following hover effect on my portfolio elements -
[link with before and after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfHbV.jpg).

I am using Bootstrap with Masonry so the HTML for the original image is looking like that:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 item">
    <img src="img/portfolio3.jpg">
</div>
```

I can use jQuery `.hover()` function to swap the image source and also I was thinking for the heading and button to have the two elements hidden before the hover event like following:

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 item">
    <img src="img/portfolio3.jpg">
    <div class="captions">
        <h3>AncaGV Blog</h3>
        <button></button>
    </div>  
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.item img').hover(function(){
    $(this).attr('src','portfolio3b.jpg');
    $(this).next().slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Please note that I've just write the code here, haven't tested yet because I want to ask if there is a possibility to use CSS for the shadow effect instead of swaping the image sources.

Also, if someone could suggest maybe a better aproach regarding the heading and the button I would be more than glad to try it out. For now I am thinking to hide the div and position it over the bottom of the image.

Comment: I think you can achieve this with CSS alone. `:hover` ?

Comment: @Roberrrt You're right, I can use it with `background: url('source-of-image.png')` and then is no need for jQuery.

Comment: I'd minimize the use of Javascript for this kind of coding. Let me wrap up some pseudo code to get you on your way.

Comment: If you are going to use the :hover with, use image/CSS sprites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Pure CSS way of solving the hidden captions:**

```
.item img + div {
    display: none;
}

.item img:hover + div {
    display: block;
}

.item:hover img + div {
    display: block;
}
```

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/robertspier/pen/ozyvKk)

**Changing the source of the image would be something like:**

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 item">
    <div id="portfolio-item-3"></div>
    <div class="captions">
        <h3>AncaGV Blog</h3>
        <button>Hi!</button>
    </div>  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#portfolio-item-1 {
    background-image: url('img.png');
}
#portfolio-item-1:hover {
    background-image: url('img-hover.png');
}
```

Comment: Side note: this won't work on mobile devices. You should add the `:focus` and `:active` state as well in addition to the `:hover`

Comment: Thank you for this, I am gonna structure it this way right now :D

Answer (score 3):

Go with `:hover`. If anything can be done by CSS, don't turn to JavaScript.

For example:

```
img {
    background: url("img.png");
}
```

Ideally, you **should** use CSS sprites for icons, flags and/or any "smaller images", by setting the `background-position`.

More on [CSS Sprites](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp).

Comment: Sprites would be good for generic items like icons, arrows, border images. But I imagine OP using jpg's as portfolio items. Still, sprites are cool. ++!

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I didn't notice the image name. :) Edited.

Comment: I haven't tried CSS Sprites that much but I can play with it regarding the button image (he will have a hover too), thank you @stormec56.

Comment: Good luck with that. :)